# swift ios как запустить анимацию во время вычислений

Tags: ios, swift, loading

Со свифтом знакома меньше недели, так что извиняюсь, если вопрос слишком глупый, но дело вот какое:

У меня есть контроллер, в котором я ввожу данные, клацаю на кнопку и перехожу к другому контроллеру, в котором производятся вычисления и выводятся на экран. Все вычисления прописаны во **viewDidLoad** второго контроллера, и если введенное значение слишком большое, то они занимают много времени. И все это время экран зависает на **первом контроллере**.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы *пока производятся вычисления на экране была гифка*, но вышло так, что сначала все считается, потом включается гифка и *тут же переход*. (subView я пробовала добавлять и в функцию кнопки и в функцию ShouldPerformSegue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе viewDidLoad вам нужно выполнять вычисления в бекграунд потоке, а пока все это вычисляется, показывать анимацию, и как только все вычисления будут закончены, в completion блоке останавливать анимацию.

Comment: Премного благодарна :)

Answer (score 5):

Как уже было сказано, вам надо выполнять код на отдельном потоке. Скорее всего в результате вычислений сделанных в отдельном потоке, вам надо будет делать апдейт информации на экране. Помните, что это обязательно делать на mainThread, то есть после вычислений вам надо указать в программе, что вы хотите выполнить какой то код в основном потоке.

Приведу несколько примеров как это сделать:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue
              (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in
        //код, который надо выполнить асинхронно здесь

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        //код, который должен выполниться в главном потоке
    })
}
```

или

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.performSelectorInBackground(Selector("backgroundTask"), withObject: nil)              
}

func backgroundTask () {
    //код, который надо выполнить асинхронно здесь
    self.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("anotherSelector"), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
}
```

или

```
let opQueue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
opQueue .addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
    //код, который надо выполнить асинхронно здесь

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() .addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        //код, который должен выполниться в главном потоке
    })
}
```