# Связка TableView и CoreData, тормозит приложение

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть два экрана: на первом выводится таблица с данными, а на втором мы эти данные добавляем.

Когда данных много - приложение начинает тормозить.

У меня такой код в viewDidLoad():

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
do {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Diary")
    let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    if result.count > 0{
        for item in result as! [NSManagedObject]{

            let date = item.valueForKey("date") as! String
            if(self.dateArr.indexOf(date)==nil){
                self.dateArr.append(date)
            }
            self.diary.append(item)

        }
    } else {
        self.dateArr = []
    }

}catch{
    //print("ERROR READ DATA!")
}
```

В нём я проверяю все данные в нашей таблице, проверяю даты в ней (что бы разбить на секции в дальнейшем) и добавляю их все в массив, что бы потом быстро с ними работать. Примерно такой код я увидел на YouTube (там не было проверки дат), может так делать нельзя и поэтому приложение тормозит? И если да, не могли бы вы подсказать как делать правильно или может подсказать какую-нибудь статью где это всё расписывается.

Comment: перенесите все ресурсоемкие задачи на отдельный поток.

Comment: вот этот ответ наверно поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458735/swift-ios-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Попробуйте добавить строку
`request.propertiesToFetch = ["date"]`
перед `executeFetchRequest`
Это должно сократить количество обращений в базу…

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых, то что ты делаешь это в viewDidLoad не сильно сказывается на работе таблицы, но как было сказано в комментах, вынести ресурсоемкие действия в отдельный поток будет хорошим решением. 
НО падение FPS таблицы зависит от разных факторов: Какой код написан в cellForRowAtIndexPath, используешь ли auto-layouts или autoresizing-mask, если первое, то правильно ли расставлены все constraints, если второе, где и как ты расставляешь элементы, так же особо важную роль играет КАКИЕ данные выводятся в ячейки таблицы, если это картинки, то кэшируешь ли ты их, подргружаешь ли асинхронно, бывает так же, что некоторые делают @property от Storyboard или .xib файла strong, что влечет за собой утечку памяти и как следствие лаги, более того, если у тебя все ячейки одного размера - это еще ок, но если динамические ячейки, то нужно обязательно кешировать их размер, если конечно, ты хочешь добиться максимально плавных таблиц. 
Вот тут есть не плохая статья про то, как можно добиться идеальных таблиц: 
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.ssbqdsgp3